# Retain Top N and Bottom N records across all the columns in a Sparse Matrix and make all other non zero elements to Zero

Tags: r

I have a large Sparse Matrix and want to retain Top N and  bottom N records from all the columns (for this example N = 2) and replace all the other non zero elements with zeros. The current approach I am following is, by generating a rank matrix for original matrix and then using it to retain Top N and bottom N elements.

The problem with this example is, total number of non zero elements across all the columns is not unique.

Below is the reproducible code.

```r
library(Matrix)
TestMatrix <- Matrix(c(0, 100, 12, 0, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
                       0, 31, 29, 0, 28, 69, 61, 0, 72, 27, 
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 19, 0, 0, 17, 33), 6, sparse = TRUE)

## number of non-zeros per column
n <- diff(TestMatrix@p)

## columns to list
lst <- split(TestMatrix@x, rep.int(1:ncol(TestMatrix), n))

## column-wise ranking and result collapsing
r <- unlist(lapply(lapply(lst, function(x) x * -1), rank))

## copy sparse matrix
RankMatrix <- TestMatrix

## replace non-zero elements with rank
RankMatrix@x <- r

#Once the rank matrix is obtained I use something like
TestMatrix[(RankMatrix <= 1) | (RankMatrix > 3)] = 0
```

This particular snippet is just trying to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: Which package are you using with the code above?

Comment: Now, I understand how to retain Top N but just not able to figure it out with Bottom N. Based on the rank matrix, if I want to select Top 10, I can easily get it by replacing N with 10. But the least or the lowest rank in every column is not one unique value.

Comment: @Mark Miller  Let me rephrase my question. I have a large Sparse Matrix (Ex: 10 x 10) and all the values  ranges from 0 to 1. The output I am looking for is same sized sparse matrix(here in this example: 10 x 10)  with all the top n ranked and bottom n ranked values  staying same as the original matrix values and all the rest of the elements will be just dots (zeros).

Comment: In your example you are retaining elements with a rank of 2 or 3.

Comment: Maybe what you are asking is how to retain elements with the two smallest ranks and the two highest ranks in each column.

Comment: "Maybe what you are asking is how to retain elements with the two smallest ranks and the two highest ranks in each column." That's right. I will update the question with working example now. Looks like I have one solution, but I will be looking for your inputs on optimizing the same. Thanks Mark.

Comment: If you have a solution I suggest posting it as an answer here.  If I come up with a different one I will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution. I am just wondering if it can be optimized while dealing with large sparse matrices.

```
TestMatrix = Matrix(c(0.80,0.9,0.6,0,0,0.3,0.5,
         0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0,
         0.4,0.5,0.6,0,0,0.1,0,
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0.3,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.7,0.8,
         0.6,0.7,0.5,0.8,0,0,0),7,sparse = TRUE)


n <- diff(TestMatrix@p)  ## number of non-zeros per column
lst <- split(TestMatrix@x, rep.int(1:ncol(TestMatrix), n))  ## columns to list
r <- unlist(lapply(lapply(lst,function(x) x * -1), rank))  ## column-wise ranking and result collapsing
RankMatrix <- TestMatrix  ## copy sparse matrix
RankMatrix@x <- r  ## replace non-zero elements with rank

#TestMatrix
#7 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

# [1,] 0.8 .   0.4 . 0.3 0.6
# [2,] 0.9 .   0.5 . 0.4 0.7
# [3,] 0.6 0.3 0.6 . 0.5 0.5
# [4,] .   .   .   . 0.2 0.8
# [5,] .   .   .   . 0.1 .  
# [6,] 0.3 .   0.1 . 0.7 .  
# [7,] 0.5 .   .   . 0.8 .  
## Function to retain Top N and Bottom N records
GetTopNBottomN <- function(aMatrix,rMatrix){
  #aMatrix = original SparseMatrix, rMatrix = RankMatrix
  n = 2 ## Top 2 and Bottom 2 Elements across all the columns
  for(j in 1:ncol(aMatrix)){ 
    MaxValue = max(rMatrix[,j])
    if(MaxValue <= 2*n) next  ##Ignore the column if there are less than or equal to 2*n nonzero values
aMatrix[(rMatrix[,j] > n & rMatrix[,j] <= MaxValue-n),j] = 0
  }   
return(aMatrix)
}

GetTopNBottomN(TestMatrix,RankMatrix)
## Obtained Output
# 7 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 
# [1,] 0.8 .   0.4 . .   0.6
# [2,] 0.9 .   0.5 . .   0.7
# [3,] .   0.3 0.6 . .   0.5
# [4,] .   .   .   . 0.2 0.8
# [5,] .   .   .   . 0.1 .  
# [6,] 0.3 .   0.1 . 0.7 .  
# [7,] 0.5 .   .   . 0.8 .
```